# branch test app link weird behaviour for facebook/twitter deep linking - iOS

Tags: ios, branch.io

I am using branch for deep linking on facebook as well as twitter. Deep linking opens up my app successfully and I am also able to retrieve all the parameters correctly. But at one instance, it stopped working and said developers are working on it and after 2 days started working again after I submitted a ticket to Branch and without me changing anything. But this weird stopping and starting of link is not good for app users. Can someone from Branch help me know the possible cause for the same, as for the live app, this would create a problem?

Comment: Branch documentation includes two types of method calls - synchronous and asynchronous calls to method that generates url. If we are using asynchronous call, it would take time to give us the url so need to check for url first before posting it on social sharing and if we are using synchronous call, we get a short url  which can be easily shared to social sites. This is what made a difference for me!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are experiencing this issue is that apps like Facebook, Twitter, Instagram and Snapchat prevent users from opening a third-party app via Universal Links. One way to mitigate this issue is to use forced redirections via URI Schemes on the in-app browser. You can enable forced redirections on Branch links by appending **$uri_redirect_mode=2** as a query parameter.

eg:

```
https://example.app.link/j93str?$uri_redirect_mode=2
```

If you are still experiencing issues, please write to integrations@branch.io with a video recording of the link redirection behavior and one of our engineers would be able to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Branch documentation includes two types of method calls - synchronous and asynchronous calls to method that generates url. If we are using asynchronous call, it would take time to give us the url so need to check for url first before posting it on social sharing and if we are using synchronous call, we get a short url which can be easily shared to social sites. This is what made a difference for me!!